# Send Data From FORM JSON; using async fetch await to PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, async-await

Since few days I try to fixed this issue. 
What it's needed:
1) post data from JSON (async fetch await) to php
2) receive the data and upload it on my server

Actually, from now, I receive an answer from my PHP but this one is empty in my console.log.

please see the code below:

Send Data From FORM JSON; using async fetch await to PHP MySQL

Thanks for your help and as usual, I continue to find the answer. This one will be post.

**the form**

```
  <form id="form">
    <div id="areachatbox"></div>
    <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" ></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
```

**the JSON:**

```
        <script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');

 form.addEventListener('click', textarea);

     async function textarea(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const msg = document.getElementById('message').value;



      const response = await fetch('chatpost.php', {
        method: 'post',
        body:JSON.stringify({msg})
      })

      const data = await response.text();
      console.log(data);
    }

    </script>
```

**and the PHP**

```
<?php 

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://localhost/XXXXXX/homepage.php'), true);

echo $json['msg'];

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know:

```
$json=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```